# Survival Analysis: Treatment not assigned at the beginning of the observation period

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival

I am new to the field of survival analysis and looking for recommendations on how to deal with the following scenario:

I have data on patients suffering from a certain disease. Some patients receive the treatment immediately, others after some time, and others never. The longer a patient suffers from the disease, the less effective the treatment might be. How would you compare the two treatment groups with the control group?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

"Never treated" is not the same as control.

In a true control, the subject is assigned a "no treatment" whereas never treated actually means they either have not already (or never got the chance to) receive the active treatment as of the time of analysis. The "no treatment" is often called a placebo, which comes from Latin *placere* meaning "to make happy"; with blinding this can be a sham treatment if there is no established standard of care, or simply receiving standard of care in a blinded or unblinded fashion. The goal is to be able to randomize this receipt to balance risk factors at baseline.

Being "never treated" is a confounding-by-indication problem. For any time point at which you declare them to be a control subject, they *could have* received the treatment at a subsequent time. A huge problem in clinical trials is when controls switch over to receive the active treatment, either because it becomes commercially available, or the study offered a cross-over arm to entice participation. A true control, then, is an artificial construct unless we can specify objective definitions of time frame and censoring. There is a whole estimand framework to consider ways of measuring treatment effect in this setting, such as time-varying covariates, accelerated failure time models, among other things.

The simple setting is considered parallel design where endpoint is followed-up without crossing over on treatment. We often set "time 0" to be *receipt of treatment* in randomized trials rather than the diagnosis of disease. Observational studies are analyzed as case cohort studies when there is no "receipt of control". Measures of disease severity, such as time since diagnosis at time of treatment, are included as (non-time varying) covariates or stratification variables.

The idea of a subject or participant receiving intervention "immediately" is also a construct, even for hospitalized subjects who code (i.e. their heart stops), the receipt of defibrillation is measured in seconds from the time the code is called. Each second turns out to be predictive of survival, not surprisingly.